# Where can I buy a concrete gate post in the style of this 1930’s gate post?

Tags: concrete, gate-post

We are about to get a wall rebuilt and it would be great if we could have gate posts that where in the same style as the rest of the road.  As I don't know the same of the style I have nothing to start with on google.
[image]

Comment: take a photo of the post to your local building merchants (not DIY store) & they **should** be able to help you.

Comment: plus a search on the web for "UK precast concrete gate post" will turn up results like this: [Gate posts from Philip Messenger Precast Stone](http://www.stoneandconcrete.co.uk/gateposts/stone_concrete_gateposts.html)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you would buy it but it would be really easy to pour it.  Just build a box the size you want the post to be.  You could put any kind of medallion or symbol at the top of it.  Pour the appropriate amount of concrete in (probably 2 bags?) Then run a vibrating sander over the outside of the form or box in order to get any air bubbles out.  Let it dry and pull the form off.

Comment: Some suitably placed rebar would need to be added too give the posts the strength they need.

Comment: The match will not be good enough, due to the detailing of the top.

Comment: yes, I forgot the rebar.

Comment: If you want a "perfect" match then take a cast of the top of the original post.